# How search a spanish word conteined ñ with grep in R?

Tags: r, twitter, encoding, character

I want to search a spanish word like "España" using grep, for exemple:

```
neg_14<-grep("CataluñaesEspaña",doc0$text,ignore.case=TRUE)
```

but what is the correct encoding? and what is the correct form to write the character "ñ"?
Thanks so much

the text that I want to analyze is:

```
str(doc0$text)
 chr [1:2858732] "RT directe indirectecat Una nit dencartellada o perqu guanyarem http//tco/Sp09q6MVvq" ...
```

and if I use this command:

```
Encoding(doc0$text)
```

the ouput is all "unknown".
I work in Linux

Comment: What is `doc0$text`? How is **that** encoded? I can do `places=c("España","Scotland"); grep("aña",places)` and it works fine because I'm encoding the places and the search string the same way.

Comment: If "unknown" is the encoding you will have to guess the encoding. Suggest you first find an element with CataluñaesEspaña in it (by grepping for "Catalu", perhaps) and then seeing if you can figure out what encoding it is. If not "UTF-8" then maybe "latin1".

Comment: I search "Catalu" for exemple and the encoding is "unknown".

Comment: And when you print it do you see the ñ? Can you extract a subset and let us see it (preferably as an R saved data file)?

Comment: Ok! thanks @Spacedman i resolve my problem, my encoding (i don't know why) is different, cataluña is catalua. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like its just dropped the letter. Now you have two problems.

Comment: @Spacedman Can I search my string only dropped the ñ in the word?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a vector with all unknown encodings:

```
> places
[1] "España"           "Scotland"         "CataluñaesEspaña" "Birmingham"      
[5] "France"           "CataluñaesEspaña"
> Encoding(places)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
```

I now have to guess. Is it "UTF-16"?

```
> iconv(places, from="UTF-16", to="UTF-8")
[1] NA                   "捓瑯慬摮"           "慃慴畬뇃敡䕳灳썡憱"
[4] "楂浲湩桧浡"         "牆湡散"             "慃慴畬뇃敡䕳灳썡憱"
```

Hmm probably not. Is it "latin1"?

```
> iconv(places, from="latin1", to="UTF-8")
[1] "EspaÃ±a"            "Scotland"           "CataluÃ±aesEspaÃ±a"
[4] "Birmingham"         "France"             "CataluÃ±aesEspaÃ±a"
```

Hmm close but not right. Is it "UTF-8" all along?

```
> iconv(places, from="UTF8", to="UTF-8")
[1] "España"           "Scotland"         "CataluñaesEspaña" "Birmingham"      
[5] "France"           "CataluñaesEspaña"
```

Well that looks about right! Lets set it!

```
> Encoding(places)="UTF-8"
> Encoding(places)
[1] "UTF-8"   "unknown" "UTF-8"   "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"
```

There's still a few left as `unknown` because they don't use any special characters.

You need to figure out what encoding your strings are in, and try this. If you select out some of the troublesome ones of your 2.8 million strings you'll be able to see when you've got it working without 2.7 million `unknown`s streaming past, which is why I suggested you grep out one or two examples with ñ in them.

Answer (score 2):

You could first change the encoding of the text, removing the `~`.  Then search for the letter `n`

```
i <- iconv("CataluñaesEspaña", from = "UTF-8", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
i
# [1] "CatalunaesEspana"
grep("n", i, value = TRUE)
# [1] "CatalunaesEspana"
```

This is linux platform-dependent. However, there is a Windows example at the bottom of `example(iconv)`

Note that since your encoding is likely different than mine, you may need to use

```
iconv(text, Encoding(text), "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this code doesn't work. My output for "i" is NA

Comment: @AngelaAndreella - Are you using Windows?

Comment: @AngelaAndreella do you get NA with exactly that input (cut and paste from here), or with *your data* as input? Because you'll get NA if your data isn't UTF-8.

Comment: FWIW copying and pasting @RichardScriven's answer works fine on Windows if you change `UTF-8` to `latin1`. @AngelaAndreella try calling `Encoding` on your character data to determine what the `from` argument should be.

Comment: @AngelaAndreella - try `iconv(text, Encoding(text), "ASCII//TRANSLIT")`

Comment: oks, then I use Encoding(doc0$text)<-"UTF-8" now. But if I use Encoding(doc0$text) that returns all "unknown". I think that it is the problem, but I don't able in character string

Comment: I use 'iconv(text, Encoding(text), "ASCII//TRANSLIT")' and return:'Error in as.character(x) :
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' '

Comment: Sorry, you should put `doc0$text` where I wrote `text`